# Applying conjugate gradient method to find optimal weight vector for portfolios

Tags: r, optimization

I have sample data of 10 stocks.

```
a<-replicate(10,rnorm(100))
cov.Rt<-cov(a)
```

I am trying to find a weight vector that minimizes the variance of returns. 
To do this I have a starting weight vector W1 and I am trying to find the weight vector that induces the maximum marginal rate of decrease in variance.

Using the conjugate gradient method I am trying to find a vector W2 subject to the condition that it is conjugate with respect to

```
W1 %*% cov.Rt %*% W2 = 0.
```

I tried the following:

First I find the first conjugate portfolio `wcg1`:

```
mat1<-rep(-1,N-1)   
mat2<-diag(1,N-1,N-1)   
mat<-rbind(mat1,mat2)
rownames(mat)<-NULL
Z<- mat %*% solve(t(mat) %*% mat) %*% t(mat)
e<-rep(1,10)
cov.Rt<-cov(a)
wcg1<- as.vector(-Z%*% t(Z) %*% cov.Rt %*% e/N)
```

then using `optim()`

```
n.iters=1
fn<-function(x,cov.Rt){as.numeric(t(x)%*%cov.Rt%*%x)}
wc<-matrix(NA,ncol=10,nrow=n.iters+1)
wc[1,]<-wcg1
for(i in n.iters) wc[i+1,]<-optim(wc[i,],fn, cov.Rt=cov.Rt)$par
```

DeMiguel et al. (http://faculty.london.edu/avmiguel/DeMiguelGarlappiNogalesUppalMS.pdf) write on page ec4 (http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/suppl/10.1287/mnsc.1080.0986/suppl_file/mnsc.1080.0986-sm-ec.pdf) that if we iterate this process N-1 times I obtain a portfolio weight vector that is identical to the minimum variance portfolio. Where N is the length of the weight vector.
However, I do not get the same results to the minimum variance portfolio.

What is wrong with my approach? 
Does the method I am using fulfil the condition the condition that the weight vector that is outputed by `optim()` is conjugate with respect to the starting vector `wcg1` (i.e. `W1 %*% cov.Rt %*% W2 = 0`)?

Comment: Why do you not build a cost function (with the weight vector as argument) returning the risk of your portfolio (variance times the vector of weights) and minimize this function using optim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, from a pure financial perspective, the risk you want to minimize on the portfolio will be the total variance which writes through the function:

```
fn<-function(x, cov.Rt) as.numeric(t(x) %*% cov.Rt %*% x)
```

Back to code, the first argument of `fn` must be the parameter you change with optim .... so `x`.
You then specify `cov.Rt` argument in `optim`:

```
optim(w1, fn, cov.Rt=cov.rt)
```

Comment: thank you, now it works. does this method fulfil the requirement mentioned above, that w2 is conjugate with respect to w1? i.e. W1 %*% cov.Rt %*% W2 = 0?

Comment: conjugate gradient method applies for definite positive matrix on a certain minimization problem. Your covariance matrix is semi-positive for sure, but you can check the positivity using eigenvalues for example.
Secondly, and most importantly, you did not formulate your initial problem properly (and that's not the place since it's just this place is just for code): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method

Is your initial problem states in solving a system of the form Ax = b or a direct varaince minimization (subject to eventually constraints?)

Comment: thank you for your help. I edited my question to make it clear what I am struggling with. thank you

Comment: Hey, just to let you know it is still not clear: N is not defined nor sample.data . But most of all, it's a code forum not a modelling one, and without a link to the paper you follow it's hard to catch up where you want to go. It tried to help you using sandard Markowitz approach and rectified your use of optim which was the original question. I am afraid comparing two methods is out of scope , but you can still provide the link.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. I added links to the paper and changed the errors in my question. Basically I am trying to reproduce what is written in the appendix linked above. I managed to get wcg1 but I am not able to figure out how to iterate the process N-1 times. Your help is very much appreciated. and of course I accept your answer since it answered my original question.

Comment: any hints would be appreciated

Comment: I have a work and an article does not take 20 mins to read, implement and test :) I will keep you in touch in the coming days however.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. I am looking forward to it. (you should only read page ec4 in the appendix)